# How can I see previous Slf4j simpleLogger output to the console?

Tags: python, java, slf4j

I have Python-based GUI, which communicates to Java-based Server over HTTP localhost. I can see current output of the Server:

```
[HTTP-Dispatcher] DEBUG src.app.Connecter - connecting to the server...
```

However I wish to have an ability to export Server logs to the file, unfortunately I cannot obtain logs of the Server by typing

```
journalctl -r
```

There is just NO server related output...

Slf4j is simply implemented in a code like:

```
 private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleServer.class);
```

I HAVE NO RIGHTS to add something to the Server config etc, I just wish to have an ability to get those Java Server logs by using some bash utilities or kinda. I'm not sure that this Java Server writes logs to the file, neither.

Comment: You say you "can see the output of the server", but the one bit of output you provide says "connecting to the server..." suggesting that it is your Python client that is producing that output.  I would suggest that you at least elaborate on what you mean by "I can see current output of the Server".  How are you seeing this output?  Be as detailed as you can.

Comment: ...in any case, your options are purely a function of what your server code is outputting and to where.  This is likely configured via some logging configuration file, often a XML file.  For example, I use the Logback logging system, so I define where I want log output to go in a "logback.xml" file.

Comment: @CryptoFool thanks for response! The main idea of the question is that I see in the console all actions that Server is performing, since Server uses Slf4j API to log it, however I wish to know, how could, or more specific, where could I found all these output that Server has printed to the console (for example if I wish to investigate them in a future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an "xml" file that describes your Slf4j logger and as I see you cannot modify the source code, so I would suggest you to run a Java Server, which uses Slf4j's simpleLogger as a logging tool with addition parameter (assuming you run your Java Server from cmd):

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=app.log
```

Where "app.log" is whatever named file where only application (in your case Java Server) logs will be stored.

So you run your Java Server:

```
java -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=app.log
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Issue is solved!